# How long can nonresident US citizens visit in the US?

Tags: us-citizens, residency

My wife and I are US citizens living in Costa Rica. We have lived in Costa Rica for the last five years, own our home here, and have received our "Permanent/Unrestricted Residency" from the Costa Rican government, having met all the government requirements over a three year period. We want to go to the US for a few months to visit family and friends around the country. How long will the US government allow us to remain in the US?

Comment: Why would you think that your time in the US would be limited?

Comment: The US government restricts the amount of time a US citizen is allowed to visit the US if that citizen is a permanent resident of a foreign country. It is however difficult to find the exact amount of time you are allowed before the US government no longer recognizes your foreign residency. I want to know what that amount of time is but the government information is extremely vague on this subject.

Comment: @DJKodiak hi could you please cite some source?  if you have a us passport, the only time-limiting factor i can think of is the 330 day requirement for http://www.irs.gov/Individuals/International-Taxpayers/Foreign-Earned-Income-Exclusion

Comment: @DJKodiak are you talking about tax obligations?

Comment: @DJKodiak That's a completely different question to the one you originally asked!

Answer (score 7):

Forever.  US citizens can stay in the US as long as they want.

Comment: The US government restricts the amount of time a US citizen is allowed to visit the US if that citizen is a permanent resident of a foreign country. It is however difficult to find the exact amount of time you are allowed before the US government no longer recognizes your foreign residency. I want to know what that amount of time is but the government information is extremely vague on this subject.

Comment: @DJKodiak are you talking about tax obligations?

Comment: @DJKodiak there's no such restriction. You're confusing with the FEIE qualifications.